# Why does the Clojure language use so many parenthesis?

Tags: syntax, clojure

It seems as if **everything** needs to be wrapped in parenthesis in clojure. Even [a simple hello world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure)!

```
(println "Hello world!")
```

What is the benefit of that syntax decision?

Comment: People, if you vote for closing. It would be nice to leave a comment to give me the chance to improve the question. Yes, the question is very short and concise but does that make a bad question?

Comment: like others said - homoiconicity, s-expressions, the beautiful and simple syntax, the easy parsing, the powerful macros, etc... In my experience, after having worked with clojure professionally for well over a year, is that you don't notice the parentheses after a couple of months. Plus there's [ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit), which "gets" LISP syntax and lets you manipulate s-expressions instead of just strings of characters. I can't live without it anymore.

Comment: Yep, this is great information and I really appreciate it. I just wonder why people downvote on the question instead of providing it as an answer. I mean learning and teaching is what we are here for, isn't it?

Comment: I think the point is that you may not try to find the answer at all.  The Wikipedia said very clearly at the beginning: "Clojure ... is recent dialect of the Lisp programming language".  Have you read the page about [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)?  Have you tried Googling?

Comment: Of course, I haven't gone down the entire rabbit whole. That's because all I wanted to know about were those parenthesis that just feeled strange to me. I'm thankful for mikera and others who cleared it up...

Comment: @Christoph: *(related but not a response to your question, hence the comment)* note that Clojure has actually *fewer* parentheses than other LISP dialects.  Also note that funnily enough by now it's pretty much accepted that a Clojure program is typically **much** shorter than the equivalent Java program...  So much shorter that the Clojure version typically contains *fewer* parentheses than the equivalent Java version : )

Comment: @TacticalCoder I guess so! Java is pretty verbose ;-) I'm a .NET guy coming from C# but also using F# from time to time. However, I'm also interested in Closure and Scala and might learn one of them for fun!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The fundamental reason is that Clojure was designed as a [homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language, i.e. code is expressed in the core data structures of the language. All Lisps share this property, but few other languages do. As a result, the entire language design of Lisps is strongly influenced by this decision.

The choice was made early in the design of Lisp that lists would be used for function invocation in the form:

```
(function arg1 arg2 arg3) => some result
```

This has lots of advantages:

- A function call is expressed as a single data object known as a "form" (in this case the form is a list, but it could also be a vector, a hashmap, a literal value etc.). You can pass it around, modify it and transform it as needed before execution.
- It's easy to construct such function calls using *standard list operations* - e.g. `(cons function-symbol list-of-args)`
- The syntax is very easy to parse - everything between two parentheses is a self-contained expression. This makes writing parsers easy, and also helps with tooling (see the incredible array of paren-handling commands in emacs for example)

The function name *could* have been put outside the parentheses:

```
function (arg1 arg2 arg3) => some result
```

But this would have many disadvantages:

- You can no longer express a function call in a single form. You'd have to pass around two separate data objects, the function name and the argument list.
- It would make the syntax more complex - you would need additional syntax rules to recognise this as a function call (e.g. extra delimiters like "," between the arguments)
- It would be harder to do code generation. Lisp was designed from the start to allow effective code generation - on the other hand if you've ever tried generating C++ source code then you will know how hard it can be in a language not designed in that way.
- It does not actually reduce the number of parentheses overall. In fact, due to being a very concise language, Clojure usually ends up with *less* parentheses than equivalent code in Java / C#

Answer (score 11):

How is Clojure's

```
(println "Hello world!")
```

any different than the

```
println("Hello world!")
```

of other languages? Same number of parentheses only at different positions.

The parens delimit a function call (as a list). In C-like languages the parens enclose only the parameters and in LISP-like languages they include the function name.

Comment: you refer to C-like languages. But for example in F# it would be just `println "Hello world!"` which means no parentheses at all!

Comment: So your question should be "Why do C and LISP-based languages use so many parentheses?". ;-) At the end of the day it is just another kind of delimiting expressions. ML-languages (like F#) use other means of delimiting than parentheses. BTW: hello-world is a rather unfortunate example for a functional language. More interesting are examples that combine multiple expressions.

Answer (score 8):

Lisp based languages use s-expressions (bracketed code) as the basis for both code and data.  This is very powerful as it gives Lisp a uniquely powerful macro system.  See also [homoiconcity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).